# Xamarin C# binding double nested collection to Switch IsToggledProperty in code

Tags: c#, xamarin, collections, binding, nested

I want to bind `Switch.IsToggledProperty` to View Model's double nested collection property using option `BindingMode.TwoWay`. In one way binding from control to View Model it works well, but when I update the property in View Model control doesn't change value. View Model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is some most important code:

View Model's property(tried with 2 arrays, but still not works):

```
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, UniversalSwitchViewModel>> _categoriesList;

    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, UniversalSwitchViewModel>> CategoriesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _categoriesList;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _categoriesList, value);
        }
    }
```

Switch control which I want to bind:

```
var checkbox = new Switch { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
//it works well only from View to View Model's property            
checkbox.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, $"{nameof(_pageViewModel.CategoriesList)}[{regionId}].Value[{categoryNameOf}].{nameof(UniversalSwitchViewModel.Value)}", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Example of change of data from code(View Model):

```
    public void SetCategoriesOption(Dictionary<string, int> categories, int regionId)
    {
        foreach (var item in categories)
        {
            CategoriesList[regionId][item.Key].Value = true;
        }

        CategoriesList = CategoriesList;
        //this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CategoriesList)); to be 100% sure I tried to run OnPropertyChanged event manually, but ofc it doesn't change anything
    }
```

Similar example which works perfect:

```
    private Dictionary<string, UniversalPickerViewModel> _selectedEnumsSettings;
    public Dictionary<string, UniversalPickerViewModel> SelectedEnumSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedEnumsSettings;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedEnumsSettings, value);
        }
    }

checkbox.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, $"{nameof(_pageViewModel.SelectedEnumSettings)}[{enumSettingKey}].{nameof(UniversalSwitchViewModel.Value)}", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

edit: forgot about UniversalSwitchViewModel

```
public class UniversalSwitchViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

edit 2 to better reproduce: 
Here is How it CategoriesList works. CategoriesList is dictionary of dictionary of UniversalSwitchViewModel where first key stores id of region(I have multiple regions with multiple switch). CategoriesList[regionId] (example: CategoriesList[0]) provides us List of switches ViewModels where key is nameOf of each category downloaded from server(don't store in this place DisplayName). CategoriesList[regionId][categoryNameOf] (Example: CategoriesList[0][discount]) return UniversalSwitchViewModel which store switch value(bool) and id to update data on server and save settings on device.

By replying to @Jack Hua - MSFT comment in binding expression I this part of code I'm binding each category downloaded from server(or settings) to its view model in property where CategoriesList is a repository of switches's view models. regionId is current selected Region Id from picker, you can assume it's equal 0 and CategoriesList has dictionary CategoriesList[0]. categoryNameOf is category.NameOf where category is item from server's settings, you can assume if you bind CategoriesList[0][xyz] there is CategoriesList contains CategoriesList[0][xyz] which return you sample UniversalSwitchViewModel with Id = 0(can be any int) and Value = true(it's simpler to check is it works).

Last example: you can bind:

```
checkbox.SetBinding(Switch.IsToggledProperty, "CategoriesList[0].Value[xyz].Value", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

and it works only as One Way Bidnding from View to View Model, so I assumed binding expression is good.

I will be glad for any suggestions.

edit 3: 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9074
https://github.com/Sobek0/BindingBugExampleXamarinForms

Comment: Can you please provide us a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What's the `regionId`, `categoryNameOf` and `CategoriesList` here, I can't reproduce the problem with the code so far.

Comment: Updated post. Now should be enough to better understend the problem. Sorry for too poor data, but it's first post, because I was always trying and be able to find solution without any custom questions.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will check it again later:).

Comment: Ok, after I creating some data and I can reproduce the problem. While I don't find a solution so far. You can create a issue in [Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) to get more help and I will update you if I find anything.

Comment: Will do it, and will upload sample project on github to download it. My mate checked this issue using WPF and the same problem exist there.

Comment: Can you please share the Github link here once you created?

Comment: Updated with links to github issue and github example solution.

Comment: OK, thanks for the link and example.